# Trouble setting up matrix with sympy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I would like to do some symbolic mathe withe some matrices. 
But my code does not work. Setting up my first matrices is 
no problem but calculating the wanted one from the start matrices does not work and I do not know why. Any suggestions?

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import Matrix , pprint, symbols



niso=4

MM = Matrix(niso-1,1, lambda i,j:var('MM_%s' % (i+1) ))
MA = Matrix (niso-1,1, lambda i,j:var('m_%s%s' % ('A', chr(66+i)) ) )
MX = Matrix (niso-1,1, lambda i,j:var('m_%s%s'% (chr(66+i), 'A')))
Rb = Matrix(niso-1,1, lambda i,j:var('Rb_%s%d' % ( chr(65)+chr(66+i)+',', i+2)))
R = Matrix (niso, niso-1, lambda i,j: var('R_%s%d' % (chr(65+i)+',' , j+1 )))



A = Matrix(niso-1,niso-1, lambda i,j:var('A_%d' % i))

for i in range(0,niso-1):
        for j in range(0,niso-1):
            A[i,j]=Rb[i,0]*MM[i,0] + MM[i,0]
```

My code only leads to this error message.

> TypeError: Can't multiply sequence by non-integer of type ''

The problem is that I thought that my matrices already contain only symbols so that multiplying should work.

Comment: I should also add that later I want to invert this matrix A and multiply this inverted matrix A with a vector called b.

Comment: Does the `sympy` documentation say you can use operators like this on `Matrix` or its elements?  This error is produced by `[1,2,3]*1.2`, which suggests that `*` is seeing a list or similar sequence without its own overloaded multiply operation.

Comment: The `type(Rb[0,0])` is `sympy.core.containers.Tuple`.  That's a `sequence`.  Try `Rb[0,0]*3`.  You are trying to multiply a `Tuple` by a `Symbol`.

Comment: So why is Rb not the same type like MM? I have check both but they are diffrent types.

Comment: The `Rb` constructor certainly looks different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved by myselfe! The Rb constructor was indeed the problem!
Changing it to

```
R = Matrix (niso, niso-1, lambda i,j: var('R_%s%d' % (chr(65+i) , j+2 )))
```

helped!